# Probability axioms (Kolmogorov)

Tags: probability-theory, logic

Has anyone ever proved the consistency of the system of probability axioms? If the answer is yes, you can specify briefly something about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The axioms for probability are not axioms for a formal system, so it doesn't really make sense to ask about "consistency" of the axioms. A probability space is just a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ such that $\mathbb P(\Omega) = 1$.

Comment: So how do you know if I can be some inconsistencies?

Comment: Measure theory can be formulated using the language of ZF, so an inconsistency would be with ZF.

Comment: "... measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$." is not enough